# Extract content from table and store in to another table in php

Tags: php, php-5.6

The  image below is a content from table. There are several contents in same table.

I need to extract data from content for save in to another table. Because I don't need full content.

I will explain which part I need from content. Please check the image.

1. In line 3 I need "Amtsgericht Stuttgart Aktenzeichen: HRB 720539"
2. In line 4 I need "26.10.2006 18:08"
3. In line 6 I need whatever is written here.
4. In line 7 I need the date "18.10.2006"
5. In line 8 I need the company name "Verlag Chrislicher Digest GmbH"

**Content from database**

```
Amtsgericht Ulm Aktenzeichen: HRB 720768 
Bekannt gemacht am: 13.03.2007 13:56&nbsp;Uhr
Die in () gesetzten Angaben der GeschÃ¤ftsanschrift und des Unternehmensgegenstandes erfolgen ohne GewÃ¤hr.
Neueintragungen
09.03.2007
MÃ¤rklin Spielwaren Vertriebs-GmbH, GÃ¶ppingen (Stuttgarter Str. 55, 73033 GÃ¶ppingen). Gesellschaft mit beschrÃ¤nkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 28.12.2006. Gegenstand: Handel mit Spielwaren aller Art. Stammkapital: 25.000,00 EUR. Allgemeine Vertretungsregelung: Ist nur ein GeschÃ¤ftsfÃ¼hrer bestellt, vertritt er allein. Sind mehrere GeschÃ¤ftsfÃ¼hrer bestellt, vertreten zwei gemeinsam oder ein GeschÃ¤ftsfÃ¼hrer mit einem Prokuristen. GeschÃ¤ftsfÃ¼hrer: Dr. Kantowsky, Jan, GrÃ¼nwald, *25.03.1968; Menrad, Karlheinz, Donzdorf-Reichenbach, *28.04.1944, jeweils einzelvertretungsberechtigt mit der Befugnis, im Namen der Gesellschaft mit sich im eigenen Namen oder als Vertreter eines Dritten RechtsgeschÃ¤fte abzuschlieÃŸen.
```

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Who keeps upvoting these bad questions. Please stop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my result using this code.

```
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$query_select                  = "SELECT id, content FROM newregister_copy";
$query_execute                 = $mysqli->query($query_select);
while($query_execute_array = $query_execute->fetch_array()) {
    $contentId                 = $query_execute_array['id'];
    $content                   = $query_execute_array['content'];
    $data                      = explode("\n", $content); //better regex for line
    //echo '<pre>';
    $filter                    = array_filter($data); // 9

    /*$count                   = count($filter);*/ //6

    /* Line Three */
    $firstElement              = current($filter); // Amtsgericht Mannheim Aktenzeichen: HRB 709650
    $explode_firstElement      = explode(':', $firstElement);
    $line_three                = $explode_firstElement[1]; //HRB 709650
    $explode_firstElementsZero = explode(' ', $explode_firstElement[0]);
    $line_three_one            = $explode_firstElementsZero[0]; //Amtsgericht
    $line_three_two            = $explode_firstElementsZero[2]; //Aktenzeichen

    /* Line Four */
    $pattern                   = '/(\d+)|AM|PM/';
    $secondElement             = next($filter); // Bekannt gemacht am: 09.07.2010 12:00 Uhr
    if(preg_match_all($pattern,$secondElement,$match))
    {
        $line_four             = $match[0][0].'-'.$match[0][1].'-'.$match[0][2].' '.$match[0][3].':'. $match[0][4]; //09-07-2010 12:00
    }

    /* Line Six */
    $lineFive                  = next($filter); // Leaved line five
    $thirdElement              = next($filter); // Neueintragungen
    $line_six                  = $thirdElement;

    /* Line Seven */
    $fourthElement             = next($filter); // 02.07.2010
    $line_seven                = str_replace('.', '-', $fourthElement);

    /* Line Eight */
    $fourthElement             = next($filter); // Detools UG (haftungsbeschrÃ¤nkt) etc
    $explode_fourthElement     = explode(',', $fourthElement);
    $line_eight                = $explode_fourthElement[0];

    $query_insert    = "INSERT INTO company(contentId,linethree,linethreeone,linethreetwo,linefour,linesix,lineseven,lineeight) VALUE ('".$contentId."', '".$line_three."', '".$line_three_one."', '".$line_three_two."', '".$line_four."', '".$line_six."', '".$line_seven."', '".$line_eight."')";
    $insert_execute  = $mysqli->query($query_insert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont find anyone to do the work for you. You need to post some code that you have so far and where exactly you are stuck. As a hint i would suggest just using regex to get the information you want.

So if all the data was stored in a string $data you could do:

```
$data = explode("/n", $string);
$firstline = $data[0];
```

Which would get the firstline of the text. Then you would need to do similar things to get the rest.

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis Thanks I will add regex and update my question.

Comment: Rahil. No dont update the question, this is not a chat room. Ask another question if you want to ask about a problem with a regex, If this answer helped you then at least give it an Upvote.

Comment: Your welcome Ben. The _eat and run brigade_ annoy me

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis Thanks for the hint explode("/n", $string).